# VBA Access read TextFile delimited by spaces

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a textfile with fixed-width strings delimited by spaces. Each row in the file represents a row of data, and each row of data consists of 5 columns.
example:

`16/08/2016    16/08/2016                           6,52   ACCREDITO
09/08/2016    09/08/2016                         206,73   ACCREDITO
03/08/2016    03/08/2016          1,00                    COMMISS. BOLLETTINO 
03/08/2016    03/08/2016        248,89                    ADDEBITO BOLLETTINO`

i tried to do this

```
Open "d:\Users\Desktop\q.txt" For Input As #1
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, NewTextLine  
    WrdArray() = Split(NewTextLine, " ")
Loop
Close #1
```

The problem is that the delimiter in split function is fixed " " but the spaces that separate the strings are not fixed so the array WrdArray contains spaces too, and i dont need spases, i would that my array contains

```
First Line:
    WrdArray(0)---->09/05/2016
    WrdArray(1)---->11/05/2016
    WrdArray(2)---->21,45
    WrdArray(3)---->0,00
    WrdArray(4)---->descrizione
Second Line
    WrdArray(0)---->09/05/2016
    WrdArray(1)---->11/05/2016
    WrdArray(2)---->0,00
    WrdArray(3)---->39,87
    WrdArray(4)---->descrizione
```

Comment: Replace all of the multiple spaces with a single space before using Split.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how many multiple spaces there are...  so  `newText = Replace(NewTextLine, "    ", " ") `  doesnt work cause i dont know the number of spaces to find

Comment: Replace any double spaces with single space until there are no more double spaces in the string.  `Do While Instr(NewTextLine, "  ")>0:NewTextLine=Replace(NewTextLine,"  "," "):Loop`

Comment: But this way could be very slowly, considerazione that in the file i Will have manu lines

Comment: Are you asking for a solution to the problem, or an argument about a performance impact that you don't know will happen?

Comment: I ask for a solution but i have to consider the execution time too.  I'm thinking about regular espression

Comment: Is that the actual data?  That looks suspiciously like fixed width to me if it has 5 columns.  How else do you tell the which element `21,45` or `39,87` belong to?

Comment: I'd agree with @Comintern, `21,45` and `39,87` would seem to be different columns. Perhaps DR and CR?

Comment: Yes they are differenti colums

Comment: Edited OP's post for clarity.

Comment: Use `Workbooks.OpenText` with fixed width and then read the range into an array - much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data consists of 5 columns, my original code for replacing the spaces (when I thought it was 4 columns) will not work. Try this:

```
Public Function GetArray2(pstrExpression As Variant)
  Dim data(4) As String

  data(0) = Trim(Mid(pstrExpression, 1, 14))
  data(1) = Trim(Mid(pstrExpression, 13, 20))
  data(2) = Trim(Mid(pstrExpression, 33, 13))
  data(3) = Trim(Mid(pstrExpression, 46, 13))
  data(4) = Trim(Mid(pstrExpression, 59, 20))

  GetArray2 = data
End Function
```

Test method:

```
Public Sub TestGetArray2()
  Dim item As Integer
  Dim data As Variant
  Dim dataLines As Variant
  Dim lineItem As Variant

  dataLines = Array("16/08/2016    16/08/2016                           6,52   ACCREDITO", _
                    "09/08/2016    09/08/2016                         206,73   ACCREDITO", _
                    "03/08/2016    03/08/2016          1,00                    COMMISS. BOLLETTINO", _
                    "03/08/2016    03/08/2016        248,89                    ADDEBITO BOLLETTINO")

  For Each lineItem In dataLines
    Debug.Print

    data = GetArray2(CStr(lineItem))

    For item = 0 To UBound(data)
      Debug.Print "Item" & item & ": " & data(item)
    Next item
  Next lineItem
 End Sub
```

Output:

```
Item0: 16/08/2016
Item1: 16/08/2016
Item2: 
Item3: 6,52
Item4: ACCREDITO

Item0: 09/08/2016
Item1: 09/08/2016
Item2: 
Item3: 206,73
Item4: ACCREDITO

Item0: 03/08/2016
Item1: 03/08/2016
Item2: 1,00
Item3: 
Item4: COMMISS. BOLLETTINO

Item0: 03/08/2016
Item1: 03/08/2016
Item2: 248,89
Item3: 
Item4: ADDEBITO BOLLETTINO
```

Comment: I was assuming your data is four columns with varying amounts of whitespace surrounding the third.  If it's actually 5 columns, then @Comintern has a pretty good point.

Comment: Infact there is the problema that there are 5 columns

Comment: Then, as @Comintern asked, how do you tell which column the data belongs to?

Comment: Never mind, obviously the way you can tell is by where the data appears on the line (I was still thinking in terms of replacing spaces).  Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Edited OP's post for clarity.

Comment: Hi , i tried your code , it's works just if you know how many spaces there are between the strings. The problem is that i download the file text and i have to populate with that information an access' table. But the spaces between the second and the third items is variable , cause it depends from how many characters is made the number  `03/08/2016    03/08/2016          1,00                    COMMISS. BOLLETTINO` 
`03/08/2016    03/08/2016        248,89                    ADDEBITO`

Comment: Then, please update your question so as to provide **_several_** lines of your data with different examples of this. In your original two-line example, the spacing appears constant, not variable. Additionally, now we are back to the question of how do you tell which column the data belongs to?

Comment: I updated the code , but i make this question: it's possible with regex expression to locate the first space after a string?

Comment: Yes, you can use something like this: `\w+(\s)`. Regarding your update, all of your data still appears to be fixed-width, so the numbers for my code's `Mid` functions may need some adjustment, but it should still work.  Also, what are "COMMISS. BOLLETTINO" and "ADDEBITO BOLLETTINO"? They contain spaces, so are they supposed to be two columns, or just one?

Comment: yes , i'm trying to adjust your code, but the problem are the numbers, i cannot foresee if there is  10000.69 or 2.48 or 10000000.69 cause i noticed that some spaces between the second, the third , and fourth fields are deleted by the numbers, how you can see in the forth row of my example. I think the key is find the first space after the string , substituite with a : and then split. Unfortunally in the last field there are spaces...

Comment: I've already adjusted the numbers based on your updated sample data, and have updated my answer accordingly.  You didn't answer my "two columns, or just one" question, so I assumed "just one".

Comment: Yes the last filed is one column but with spaces inside the text